# RunTimeError Error creating new content types. Django 1.8.6 How to fix?

Tags: django, postgresql-9.3, django-migrations, django-1.8, django-contenttypes

Have created almost all of my models and I get this error in one model in particular (not all of them).

***Error creating new content types. Please make sure contenttypes is migrated before trying to migrate apps individually.***

It occurs when I'm accessing the model through Django admin. I am have NOT migrated from one version of Django to another - so the contenttypes table does not have the 'name' column. It has the fields id, app_label and model.

I have tried migrating contenttypes. Some apps I can migrate others will throw the same error I see in the browser accessing the model in the admin page.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated!

Python version is 2.7.6
Database - Postgres 9.3

UPDATED QUESTION 12/7/15: 
I seem to be running in circles - getting several errors related to this issue.

Here is another error I get in trying to resolve this issue:

Programming Error: Permission denied for sequence django_migrations_seq
(when trying to do a fake migration)

Programming Error: relation "employees_employee" already exits
(when trying to run a normal migration)

3 of the Models I'm having an issue with are database views (not actual tables).

This seems to be a combination of a postgres and django error - not one or the other. No idea what to do at this point - keep going in circles between these errors.

Have checked all permissions, grants, etc... all is good there.

Thanks!